# Str object not callable in Python?

Tags: python, string

I am trying to make a simple magic eight ball program that asks a question, gives a random response, and then prompts the user if they want to try again.
Everything works up until the "ask again" part where all hell breaks loose and this error appears:

**TypeError: 'str' object is not callable**

I am still very new to Python and quite honestly probably just making a rookie mistake, but there's no shame in asking for help I believe.

Here is the code:

```
def question():
    question = str(input("Ask a yes or no question: "))

    replies = ["It is certain",
     "It is decidedly so",
     "Without a doubt",
     "Yes definitely",
     "You may rely on it",
     "As I see it, yes",
     "Most likely",
     "Outlook good",
     "Yes",
     "Signs point to yes",
     "Reply hazy try again",
     "Ask again later",
     "Better not tell you now",
     "Cannot predict now",
     "Concentrate and ask again",
     "Don't count on it",
     "My reply is no",
     "My sources say no",
     "Outlook not so good",
     "Very doubtful",
               ]

    rand_num = random.randint(0, 20)

    print(replies[rand_num])

    def ask_again():
        again = input("Would you like to ask another question? (Y/N): ")
        if again == "Y" or "y":
            question()
        elif again == "N" or "n":
            print("Thank you and goodbye.")
        else:
            print("That is not an acceptable answer.")
            ask_again()
    ask_again()
question()
```

Comment: `again == "Y" or "y"` does not do what you think it does, see [How do I test one variable against multiple values?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15112125)

Comment: You used the name `question` for two different things: a function *and* a string. It can't be both, rename one or the other.

Comment: You want to avoid using recursion to repeatedly ask a question. See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](//stackoverflow.com/q/23294658)

Answer (score 2):

```
def question(): # <<<<< here you define `question` as the function
    question = str(input("Ask a yes or no question: ")) # <<< and here you "shadow" that with a string (see below the long explanation).
```

Then, later in the function definition:

```
def ask_again():
        again = input("Would you like to ask another question? (Y/N): ")
        if again == "Y" or "y":
            question() # <<< here, question is not a function anymore because you redefined the name `question` to a string on the second line of the function definition
```

#### What's going on?

When you `def` the function `question()`, you essentially define an object with name `question` that is associated with your function's code.
In your function definition, however, the first thing you do is *redefine* the object `question`, assigning to it a string. This means that, *inside the function definition scope*, when you use `question` you're not referring to he function anymore, but to the string assigned to that object.

Thus the error when you do `question()` **inside the definition** in the line I marked above. 
At this point, you're not calling a function, but trying to "call" a string, which raises the error you're getting.

**Note:** Outside of the definition of the function `question`, calling `question()` will actually run the function, because you shadow the object only in the function definition's scope.

Comment: They don't overwrite anything. The function is a global, the string a local. But the local is used when they expected it to be the function.

Comment: And thus, the name `question` gets redefined. I'm rewording the answer to use more proper definitions

Comment: It's still not the correct term. They are *shadowing* the global name (here as a closure).

Comment: I'm afraid I'm lacking lexicon to properly explain what is going on here with the necessary detail. I'm open for suggestions on how to improve the answer, though

Comment: It's already better; `ask_again()` finds the `question` name in the parent scope (the local namespace of the `question` function), rather than the `question` name in the global scope. Apart from using a different name, you could also fix it by telling Python to look for a global by adding the `global question` statement in the `ask_again()` function. But that'd be akin to binding your broken leg with a spalk to continue walking rather than have the bone set properly. :-)

Comment: If you want to improve your lexicon, read [*Resolution of names*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#resolution-of-names).

Comment: Thanks for the link!